# How can I use the MIST library to de-identify a text?

Tags: nlp

I wonder how I use can the [MIST library](http://mist-deid.sourceforge.net/) to de-identify a text, e.g., transforming

```
Patient ID: P89474

Mary Phillips is a 45-year-old woman with a history of diabetes.
She arrived at New Hope Medical Center on August 5 complaining
of abdominal pain. Dr. Gertrude Philippoussis diagnosed her
with appendicitis and admitted her at 10 PM.
```

to

```
Patient ID: [ID]

[NAME] is a [AGE]-year-old woman with a history of diabetes.
She arrived at [HOSPITAL] on [DATE] complaining
of abdominal pain. Dr. [PHYSICIAN] diagnosed her
with appendicitis and admitted her at 10 PM.
```

I've wandered through the documentation but no luck so far.

Comment: good luck doing this on actual patient data and guaranteeing 100% that you won't "miss" something that should've been obscured...

Comment: @MarcB it's okay I'm not aiming for 100% (I wish though) :) I don't expect patient notes to be that clean either.

Comment: @MarcB We got some decent results though: *Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee, Ozlem Uzuner, Peter Szolovits. [De-identification of Patient Notes with Recurrent Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475). arXiv preprint arXiv:1606.03475, 2016.*

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That is an interesting paper. Will the the software be made available at some point?

Comment: @tkja probably in the future but unsure when

Comment: @tkja we have released the code: https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thanks for the update, looking forward to check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was tested on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with Anaconda Python 2.7.11 x64, and MIST 2.0.4. MIST 2.0.4 does not work with Python 3.x (according to the manual, I haven't tested it myself).

MIST (MITRE Identification Scrubber Toolkit) [1] is a customization of MAT (MITRE Annotation Toolkit), which is a tool to tag documents automatically or with humans (for the latter it provides a GUI via webserver). The automatic tagger is based on [Carafe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/carafe/) (ConditionAl RAndom Fields) [2], which is an OCaml implementation of conditional random fields (CRF).

MIST does not come with any trained model, and is has only ~10 short, non-medical documents annotated with typical NER class (like organization and person).

De-id (de-identification) is the process of tagging PHIs (Private Health Information) in a document, and replacing them with fake data. Let's ignore PHI replacement for now, and focus on tagging. In order to tag a document (e.g., a patient note), MAT follows a typical machine learning scheme: the CRF needs to be trained on a labeled dataset (= a set of labeled documents), then we use it to tag unlabeled documents.

The main technical concept in MAT is tasks. A task is a set of activities, called workflows, which can be broken down into steps. Named-entity recognition (NER) is one task. De-id is another task (mostly, NER geared toward medical texts): in other words, MIST is just one task of MAT (actually 3: core, HIPAA, and AMIA. Core is a parent task, while HIPAA and AMIA are two different tagets). Steps are for example tokenization, tagging, or cleaning. Workflows are just list of steps that one may follow.

With this in mind, here is the code for **Microsoft Windows**:

```
#######
rem Instructions for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
rem Installing MIST: set MAT_PKG_HOME depending on where you downloaded it
SET MAT_PKG_HOME=C:\Users\Francky\Downloads\MIST_2_0_4\MIST_2_0_4\src\MAT
SET TMP=C:\Users\Francky\Downloads\MIST_2_0_4\MIST_2_0_4\temp
cd C:\Users\Francky\Downloads\MIST_2_0_4\MIST_2_0_4
python install.py

# MAT is now installed. We'll show how to use it for NER.
# We will be taking snippets from some of the 8 tutorials.
# A lot of the tutorial content are about the annotation GUI, 
# which we don't care here.

# Tuto 1: install task
cd %MAT_PKG_HOME%
bin\MATManagePluginDirs.cmd install %CD%\sample\ne

# Tuto 2: build model (i.e., train it on labeled dataset)
bin\MATModelBuilder.cmd --task "Named Entity" --model_file %TMP%\ne_model ^
--input_files "%CD%\sample\ne\resources\data\json\*.json"

# Tuto 2: Add trained model as the default model
bin\MATModelBuilder.cmd --task "Named Entity" --save_as_default_model ^
--input_files "%CD%\sample\ne\resources\data\json\*.json"

# Tudo 5: use CLI -> prepare the document
bin\MATEngine.cmd --task "Named Entity" --workflow Demo --steps "zone,tokenize" ^
--input_file %CD%\sample\ne\resources\data\raw\voa2.txt --input_file_type raw ^
--output_file %CD%\voa2_txt.json --output_file_type mat-json

# Tuto 5: use CLI -> tag the document
bin\MATEngine.cmd --task "Named Entity" --workflow Demo --steps "tag" ^
--input_file %CD%\voa2_txt.json --input_file_type mat-json ^
--output_file %CD%\voa2_txt.json --output_file_type mat-json ^
--tagger_local
```

NER is now done.

Here are the same instructions for **Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64**:

```
#######
# Instructions for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64
# Installing MIST: set MAT_PKG_HOME depending on where you downloaded it
export MAT_PKG_HOME=/home/ubuntu/mist/MIST_2_0_4/MIST_2_0_4/src/MAT
export TMP=/home/ubuntu/mist/MIST_2_0_4/MIST_2_0_4/temp
mkdir $TMP
cd /home/ubuntu/mist/MIST_2_0_4/MIST_2_0_4/
python install.py

# MAT is now installed. We'll show how to use it for NER.
# We will be taking snippets from some of the 8 tutorials.
# A lot of the tutorial content are about the annotation GUI, 
# which we don't care here.

# Tuto 1: install task
cd $MAT_PKG_HOME
bin/MATManagePluginDirs install $PWD/sample/ne

# Tuto 2: build model (i.e., train it on labeled dataset)
bin/MATModelBuilder --task "Named Entity" --model_file $TMP/ne_model \
--input_files "$PWD/sample/ne/resources/data/json/*.json"

# Tuto 2: Add trained model as the default model
bin/MATModelBuilder --task "Named Entity" --save_as_default_model \
--input_files "$PWD/sample/ne/resources/data/json/*.json"

# Tudo 5: use CLI -> prepare the document
bin/MATEngine --task "Named Entity" --workflow Demo --steps "zone,tokenize" \
--input_file $PWD/sample/ne/resources/data/raw/voa2.txt --input_file_type raw \
--output_file $PWD/voa2_txt.json --output_file_type mat-json

# Tuto 5: use CLI -> tag the document
bin/MATEngine --task "Named Entity" --workflow Demo --steps "tag" \
--input_file $PWD/voa2_txt.json --input_file_type mat-json \
--output_file $PWD/voa2_txt.json --output_file_type mat-json \
--tagger_local
```

---

To run de-id, there is no need to install the de-id tasks are they are pre-installed. There are 2 de-id tasks (`\MIST_2_0_4\src\tasks\HIPAA\task.xml` and `\MIST_2_0_4\src\tasks\AMIA\task.xml`). They don't come with any trained model nor labeled dataset, so you may want to get some data at [Physician notes with annotated PHI](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6676/1652).

For **Microsoft Windows** ( tested with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate ):

To train the model (you can replace `HIPAA Deidentification` with `AMIA Deidentification` depending on the tagset you wish to use):

```
bin\MATModelBuilder.cmd --task "HIPAA Deidentification"  ^
--save_as_default_model --nthreads=3   --max_iterations=15  ^
--lexicon_dir="%CD%\sample\mist\gazetteers"  ^
--input_files "%CD%\sample\mist\i2b2-60-00-40\train\*.json"
```

To run the trained model on one file:

```
bin\MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo ^
--input_file .\note.txt --input_file_type raw ^
--output_file .\note.json --output_file_type mat-json ^
--tagger_local ^
--steps "clean,zone,tag"
```

To run the trained model on one directory:

```
bin\MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo ^
--input_dir "%CD%\sample\test" --input_file_type raw ^
--output_dir "%CD%\sample\test" --output_file_type mat-json ^
--tagger_local ^
--steps "clean,zone,tag"
```

As usual, one can specify the input file format to be JSON:

```
bin\MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo ^
 --input_dir "%CD%\sample\mist\i2b2-60-00-40\test" --input_file_type mat-json ^
 --output_dir "%CD%\sample\mist\i2b2-60-00-40\test_out" --output_file_type mat-json ^
 --tagger_local --steps "tag"
```

For **Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64**:

To train the model (you can replace `HIPAA Deidentification` with `AMIA Deidentification` depending on the tagset you wish to use):

```
bin/MATModelBuilder --task "HIPAA Deidentification"  \
--save_as_default_model --nthreads=20   --max_iterations=15  \
--lexicon_dir="$PWD/sample/mist/gazetteers"  \
--input_files "$PWD/sample/mist/i2b2-60-00-40/train/*.json"
```

To run the trained model on one file:

```
bin/MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo \
--input_file ./note.txt --input_file_type raw \
--output_file ./note.json --output_file_type mat-json \
--tagger_local \
--steps "clean,zone,tag"
```

To run the trained model on one directory:

```
bin/MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo \
--input_dir "$PWD/sample/test" --input_file_type raw \
--output_dir "$PWD/sample/test" --output_file_type mat-json \
--tagger_local \
--steps "clean,zone,tag"
```

As usual, one can specify the input file format to be JSON:

```
bin/MATEngine --task "HIPAA Deidentification" --workflow Demo \
 --input_dir "$PWD/sample/mist/i2b2-60-00-40/test" --input_file_type mat-json \
 --output_dir "$PWD/sample/mist/i2b2-60-00-40/test_out" --output_file_type mat-json \
 --tagger_local --steps "tag"
```

---

Typical error messages:

- `raise PluginError, "Carafe not configured properly for this task and workflow: " + str(e)` (when trying to tag a document): it often means that no model was specified. You need to either defined a default model, or use `--tagger_model /path/to/model/`.
- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` (when training a model): it's easy to go over the heap_size limit ( the default is 2GB ). You can increase the heap_size with the `--heap_size` parameter. Example (Linux):

  ```
  bin/MATModelBuilder --task "HIPAA Deidentification"  \
  --save_as_default_model --nthreads=20   --max_iterations=15  \
  --lexicon_dir="$PWD/sample/mist/gazetteers"  \
  --heap_size=60G \
  --input_files "$PWD/sample/mist/mimic-140-20-40/train/*.json"
  ```

---

[1] John Aberdeen, Samuel Bayer, Reyyan Yeniterzi, Ben Wellner, Cheryl Clark, David Hanauer, Bradley Malin, Lynette Hirschman, The MITRE identification scrubber toolkit: design, training, and assessment, Int. J. Med. Informatics 79 (12) (2010) 849–859, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijmedinf.2010.09.007.

[2] B. Wellner, Sequence Models and Ranking Methods for
Discourse Parsing [Ph.D. Dissertation]. Brandeis University,
Waltham, MA, 2009. http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~wellner/pubs/wellner_dissertation.pdf

---

Documentation for `MATModelBuilder.cmd`:

```
Usage: MATModelBuilder.cmd [task option] [config name option] [other options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  Task option:
    --task=task         name of the task to use. Must be the first argument,
                        if present. Obligatory if the system knows of more
                        than one task. Known tasks are: AMIA Deidentification,
                        Named Entity, HIPAA Deidentification, Enhanced Named
                        Entity

  Config name option:
    --config_name=name  name of the model build config to use. Must be the
                        first argument after --task, if present. Optional.
                        Default model build config will be used if no config
                        is specified.

  Control options:
    --version           Print version number and exit
    --debug             Enable debug output.
    --subprocess_debug=int
                        Set the subprocess debug level to the value provided,
                        overriding the global setting. 0 disables, 1 shows
                        some subprocess activity, 2 shows all subprocess
                        activity.
    --subprocess_statistics
                        Enable subprocess statistics (memory/time), if the
                        capability is available and it isn't globally enabled.
    --tmpdir_root=dir   Override the default system location for temporary
                        files. If the directory doesn't exist, it will be
                        created. Use this feature to control where temporary
                        files are created, for added security, or in
                        conjunction with --preserve_tempfiles, as a debugging
                        aid.
    --preserve_tempfiles
                        Preserve the temporary files created, as a debugging
                        aid.
    --verbose_config    If specified, print to stderr the source of each MAT
                        configuration variable the first time it's accessed.

  Options for model class creation:
    --partial_training_on_gold_only
                        When the trainer is presented with partially tagged
                        documents, by default MAT will ask it to train on all
                        annotated segments, completed or not. If this flag is
                        specified, only completed segments should be used for
                        training.
    --feature_spec=FEATURE_SPEC
                        path to the Carafe feature spec file to use. Optional
                        if feature_spec is set in the <build_settings> for the
                        relevant model config in the task.xml file for the
                        task.
    --training_method=TRAINING_METHOD
                        If present, specify a training method other than the
                        standard method. Currently, the only recognized value
                        is psa. The psa method is noticeably faster, but may
                        result in somewhat poorer results. You can use a value
                        of '' to override a previously specified training
                        method (e.g., a default method in your task).
    --max_iterations=MAX_ITERATIONS
                        number of iterations for the optimized PSA training
                        mechanism to use. A value between 6 and 10 is
                        appropriate. Overrides any possible default in
                        <build_settings> for the relevant model config in the
                        task.xml file for the task.
    --lexicon_dir=LEXICON_DIR
                        If present, the name of a directory which contains a
                        Carafe training lexicon. This pathname should be an
                        absolute pathname, and should have a trailing slash.
                        The content of the directory should be a set of files,
                        each of which contains a sequence of tokens, one per
                        line. The name of the file will be used as a training
                        feature for the token. Overrides any possible default
                        in <build_settings> for the relevant model config in
                        the task.xml file for the task.
    --parallel          If present, parallelizes the feature expectation
                        computation, which reduces the clock time of model
                        building when multiple CPUs are available
    --nthreads=NTHREADS
                        If --parallel is used, controls the number of threads
                        used for training.
    --gaussian_prior=GAUSSIAN_PRIOR
                        A positive float, default is 10.0. See the jCarafe
                        docs for details.
    --no_begin          Don't introduce begin states during training. Useful
                        if you're certain that you won't have any adjacent
                        spans with the same label. See the jCarafe
                        documentation for more details.
    --l1                Use L1 regularization for PSA training. See the
                        jCarafe docs for details.
    --l1_c=L1_C         Change the penalty factor for the L1 regularizer. See
                        the jCarafe docs for details.
    --heap_size=HEAP_SIZE
                        If present, specifies the -Xmx argument for the Java
                        JVM
    --stack_size=STACK_SIZE
                        If present, specifies the -Xss argument for the Java
                        JVM
    --tags=TAGS         if present, a comma-separated list of tags to pass to
                        the training engine instead of the full tag set for
                        the task (used to create per-tag pre-tagging models
                        for multi-stage training and tagging)
    --pre_models=PRE_MODELS
                        if present, a comma-separated list of glob-style
                        patterns specifying the models to include as pre-
                        taggers.
    --add_tokens_internally
                        If present, Carafe will use its internal tokenizer to
                        tokenize the document before training. If your
                        workflow doesn't tokenize the document, you must
                        provide this flag, or Carafe will have no tokens to
                        base its training on. We recommend strongly that you
                        tokenize your documents separately; you should not use
                        this flag.
    --word_properties=WORD_PROPERTIES
                        See the jCarafe docs for --word-properties.
    --word_scores=WORD_SCORES
                        See the jCarafe docs for --word-scores.
    --learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE
                        See the jCarafe docs for --learning-rate.
    --disk_cache=DISK_CACHE
                        See the jCarafe docs for --disk_cache.

  Input options:
    --input_dir=dir     A directory, all of whose files will be used in the
                        model construction. Can be repeated. May be specified
                        with --input_files.
    --input_files=re    A glob-style pattern describing full pathnames to use
                        in the model construction. May be specified with
                        --input_dir. Can be repeated.
    --file_type=fake-xml-inline | mat-json | xml-inline
                        The file type of the input. One of fake-xml-inline,
                        mat-json, xml-inline. Default is mat-json.
    --encoding=encoding
                        The encoding of the input. The default is the
                        appropriate default for the file type.

  Output options:
    --model_file=file   Location to save the created model. The directory must
                        already exist. Obligatory if --save_as_default_model
                        isn't specified.
    --save_as_default_model
                        If the the task.xml file for the task specifies the
                        <default_model> element, save the model in the
                        specified location, possibly overriding any existing
                        model.
```

Documentation for `MATEngine`:

```
Usage: MATEngine [core options] [input/output/task options] [other options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  Core options:
    --other_app_dir=dir
                        additional directory to load a task from. Optional and
                        repeatable.
    --settings_file=file
                        a file of settings to use which overwrites existing
                        settings. The file should be a Python config file in
                        the style of the template in
                        etc/MAT_settings.config.in. Optional.
    --task=task         name of the task to use. Obligatory if the system
                        knows of more than one task. Known tasks are: AMIA
                        Deidentification, Named Entity, HIPAA
                        Deidentification, Enhanced Named Entity
    --version           Print version number and exit
    --debug             Enable debug output.
    --subprocess_debug=int
                        Set the subprocess debug level to the value provided,
                        overriding the global setting. 0 disables, 1 shows
                        some subprocess activity, 2 shows all subprocess
                        activity.
    --subprocess_statistics
                        Enable subprocess statistics (memory/time), if the
                        capability is available and it isn't globally enabled.
    --tmpdir_root=dir   Override the default system location for temporary
                        files. If the directory doesn't exist, it will be
                        created. Use this feature to control where temporary
                        files are created, for added security, or in
                        conjunction with --preserve_tempfiles, as a debugging
                        aid.
    --preserve_tempfiles
                        Preserve the temporary files created, as a debugging
                        aid.
    --verbose_config    If specified, print to stderr the source of each MAT
                        configuration variable the first time it's accessed.
```